# NSPredicate with block - how does it work

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a search mechanism in my application and thus far an object of `NSPredicate` is used to filter objects.

I'm pretty confused because of the magic happening in the runtime of my program. In my program there is an array with names and another mutable array with filtered names declared as properties.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *names;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredNames;
```

I initialize the array with names when the view is loaded.

```
self.names = @[
               @"Aeron",
               @"Brandon",
               @"Chris",
               @"David",
               @"Elvis",
               @"Francisco",
               @"George",
               @"Oliver",
               @"Lary",
               @"Neythan",
               @"Marcus",
               @"Phil"
               ];
```

Then I setup a table view and its content, install search mechanism (with iOS 8's one, i.e. `UISearchController`). And here we go, I implement the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol and my `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` is presented below.

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    NSString *input = searchController.searchBar.text;
    if (input.length > 0) {
        [self.filteredNames removeAllObjects];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            NSLog(@"Got [%@] string.", evaluatedObject);
            NSRange range = [evaluatedObject rangeOfString:input options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            return range.location != NSNotFound;
        }];

        NSArray *matches = [self.names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [self.filteredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

        [((UITableViewController *)self.searchController.searchResultsController).tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

So it works perfectly. But I wonder, why do I get an iteration of my array with names inside of the block? I know that blocks are good due to their specification of saving their frame from a stack with all variables and certain values for the moment in past, therefore they can be executed lately. But why does the block iterate this particular array? I tried to declare a new one and initialize it (since I thought it took all collections and their values), but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. "Why does the block iterate this particular array?" You mean the `self.names` array? That's because you are running the filter function on it. When you tried to "initialise a new one" then you say it didn't work. What code did you use to do this and what **specifically** didn't work? i.e. what did it do etc... "It didn't work" is the least useful analysis of a problem imaginable.

Comment: Thank you! I need a new pair of eyes! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter the array, you have to iterate through every element and test it against the predicate block.  I believe the behaviour you're experiencing is intended.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that I sent a message with block and was wondering where the data did come from. :-D